# How to plot groupby as percentage in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a binary classification problem, which I want to solve with a RandomForestClassifier. My target column is 'successful' which is either 0 or 1. I want to investigate the data, and see how it looks like. For that I tried to do count plots by category. But it's not saying how much in percentage from total are 'successful' (i.e. successful == 1)

How can I change the following plot, so that these subplots display the percentage of (successful == 1) of total of all posts? (Let's say in category weekday, in day 'Saturday' I have 10 datapoints, 7 of them are successful ('successful' == 1), so I want to have a bar with points at that day at 0.7.

Here is the actual plot (counts :-/):

[image: actual count plot]

And here is a part of my dataframe:

[image: 15 samples of my df]

And here is the actual code used to generate the actual plot:

```
# Plot 

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

x_vals = [['page_name', 'weekday'],['type', 'industry']]
subtitles = [['by Page', 'by Weekday'],['by Content Type', 'by Industry']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(15,10))
#jitter = [[False, 1], [0.5, 0.2]]

for j in range(len(ax)):
    for i in range(len(ax[j])):
        ax[j][i].tick_params(labelsize=15)
        ax[j][i].set_xlabel('label', fontsize=17, position=(.5,20))
        if (j == 0) :
            ax[j][i].tick_params(axis="x", rotation=50) 
        ax[j][i].set_ylabel('label', fontsize=17)
        ax[j][i] = sns.countplot(x=x_vals[j][i], hue="successful", data=mainDf, ax=ax[j][i])

for j in range(len(ax)):
    for i in range(len(ax[j])):
        ax[j][i].set_xlabel('', fontsize=17)
        ax[j][i].set_ylabel('count', fontsize=17)
        ax[j][i].set_title(subtitles[j][i], fontsize=18)

fig.suptitle('Success Count by Category', position=(.5,1.05), fontsize=20)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

PS: Please not, I am using Seaborn. Solution should be also with Seaborn, if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`barplot`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJQ8J.png) here. I wasn't 100% sure of what you actually want to achieve so I developed several solutions.

**Frequency of successful (unsuccessful) per total successful (unsuccessful)**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))

mainDf['frequency'] = 0 # a dummy column to refer to
for col, ax in zip(['page_name', 'weekday', 'type', 'industry'], axes.flatten()):
    counts = mainDf.groupby([col, 'successful']).count()
    freq_per_group = counts.div(counts.groupby('successful').transform('sum')).reset_index()
    sns.barplot(x=col, y='frequency', hue='successful', data=freq_per_group, ax=ax)
```

[image]

**Frequency of successful (unsuccessful) per group**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))

mainDf['frequency'] = 0 # a dummy column to refer to
for col, ax in zip(['page_name', 'weekday', 'type', 'industry'], axes.flatten()):
    counts = mainDf.groupby([col, 'successful']).count()
    freq_per_group = counts.div(counts.groupby(col).transform('sum')).reset_index()
    sns.barplot(x=col, y='frequency', hue='successful', data=freq_per_group, ax=ax)
```

which, based on the data you provided, gives

[image]

**Frequency of successful (unsuccessful) per total**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))

mainDf['frequency'] = 0 # a dummy column to refer to
total = len(mainDf)
for col, ax in zip(['page_name', 'weekday', 'type', 'industry'], axes.flatten()):
    counts = mainDf.groupby([col, 'successful']).count()
    freq_per_total = counts.div(total).reset_index()
    sns.barplot(x=col, y='frequency', hue='successful', data=freq_per_total, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Even more detailled than what I needed. Just one plot didn't work. The one of the "Frequency of successful (unsuccessful) per total" I get an error at the sns.barplot line, saying this: "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" I think python don't like the func passed to the "estimator"

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that out. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Hey @ayorgo is there a possibility to display these data in a tabular way? So that the exact numeric values are readable?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `ax[j][i] = sns.countplot(x=x_vals[j][i], hue="successful", data=mainDf, ax=ax[j][i])` to `ax[j][i] = sns.barplot(x=x_vals[j][i], y='successful', data=mainDf, ax=ax[j][i], ci=None, estimator=lambda x: sum(x) / len(x) * 100)`

Your code would be

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

x_vals = [['page_name', 'weekday'],['type', 'industry']]
subtitles = [['by Page', 'by Weekday'],['by Content Type', 'by Industry']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(15,10))
#jitter = [[False, 1], [0.5, 0.2]]

for j in range(len(ax)):
    for i in range(len(ax[j])):
        ax[j][i].tick_params(labelsize=15)
        ax[j][i].set_xlabel('label', fontsize=17, position=(.5,20))
        if (j == 0) :
            ax[j][i].tick_params(axis="x", rotation=50) 
        ax[j][i].set_ylabel('label', fontsize=17)
        ax[j][i] = sns.barplot(x=x_vals[j][i], y='successful', data=mainDf, ax=ax[j][i], ci=None, estimator=lambda x: sum(x) / len(x) * 100)

for j in range(len(ax)):
    for i in range(len(ax[j])):
        ax[j][i].set_xlabel('', fontsize=17)
        ax[j][i].set_ylabel('percent', fontsize=17)
        ax[j][i].set_title(subtitles[j][i], fontsize=18)

fig.suptitle('Success Percentage by Category', position=(.5,1.05), fontsize=20)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```